# Why meta description tag is not showing on Google

Tags: html, seo, meta-tags

There are a few web pages. Index page's description tag is showing on Google but other page's description tag is not showing. Why is that? What should I do for show them on Google?

```
<meta name="description" content="This is the description tag">
```

Comment: What do you mean with "show them to Google"?

Comment: @Ant When searching the website on google, the screen you see...

Answer (score 5):

Google’s main focus is to help users to get the right content to answer their questions, and to solve their problems. If your meta description is not well-written, when compared to the content of the page and the user's specific search phrase doing a good job of doing that, Google might show something different on the SERPs (Search Engine Result Pages). In other possibility, the meta description you specified is too short or too long.

A similar thing you can see for the title. Sometimes, Google is not your Title Tag. We also faced the same issue for our website but we successfully solved our issues.

**Google set our Meta Description:**
[image: Google Showed Us like this]

**How we solved this issue:**

In ***Google Search Console***, goto ***Clear Cached URL*** option in Removals, that allows one to Keep URL(s) in Google Search results, just clear current snippet and cached version until the next crawl.

**Now Google is showing original Meta Description:**
[image: We set meta description for our website]

**Here is more information, just in case it's helpful:**

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9689846#clear_cache_request

Answer (score 3):

What Google shows in the description of their results (also known as "snippets") is not always your meta-description.

As per google's explanation:

> Google's generation of page titles and descriptions (or "snippets") is completely automated and takes into account both the content of a page as well as references to it that appear on the web. The goal of the snippet and title is to best represent and describe each result and explain how it relates to the user's query.

> We use a number of different sources for this information, including descriptive information in the title and meta tags for each page. We may also use publicly available information, or create rich results based on markup on the page.

If you want, you can disable the generation of those snippets with `nosnippet` meta tag, but apart from that there is little you can do to influence what is shown in those snippets, as explained by Google [here](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/appearance/good-titles-snippets)